# Nginx load balancing with Node.js and Google Oauth

Tags: google-oauth

I created a Node.js site that uses Google authentication. The site is used by 100+ users concurrently which affect the  performance. So I understand that Nginx could help in scaling the site by creating multiple instance of the Node.js app in multiple ports and then we use Nginx as a load balancer.

So, I configured Nginx, but the issue is that it dose not seem to work with Google authentication. I am able to see the first page of my site and I am able to to login via Google but it is dose not work after this point.

Any suggestions to what could be missing to make this work.

This is my configuration file:

```
upstream my_app 
{
    least_conn;                 # Use Least Connections strategy
    server ip:3001;      # NodeJS Server 2 I changed the actual ip
    server ip:3002;      # NodeJS Server 3
    server ip:3003;      # NodeJS Server 4
    server ip:3004;      # NodeJS Server 5
    keepalive 256;
 }


server {
    listen 80 default_server;
    listen [::]:80 default_server ipv6only=on;
    expires epoch;
    add_header Cache-Control "no-cache, public, must-revalidate, proxy-revalidate";
   server_name ip;
   access_log /var/log/nginx/example.com-access.log;
   error_log  /var/log/nginx/example.com-error.log error;

   # Browser and robot always look for these
   # Turn off logging for them
   location = /favicon.ico { log_not_found off; access_log off; }
   location = /robots.txt  { log_not_found off; access_log off; }
   # pass the request to the node.js server
   # with some correct headers for proxy-awareness
   location / {
       proxy_set_header X-Real-IP $remote_addr;
       proxy_set_header X-Forwarded-For $proxy_add_x_forwarded_for;
       proxy_set_header Host $http_host;
       proxy_set_header X-NginX-Proxy true;
       proxy_buffers 8 16k;
       proxy_buffer_size 32k;
       proxy_pass http://my_app ;
       proxy_redirect off ;
       add_header Pragma "no-cache";

       # Handle Web Socket connections
       proxy_http_version 1.1;
       proxy_set_header Upgrade $http_upgrade;
       proxy_set_header Connection "upgrade";
      }

 }
```

I just started learning about nginx, I checked when the upstream have only one ip address and it is working. i.e it works as a reverse proxy but not as a load balancer and my guess is due to google authentication nature.

And the error I receive in the error log is connection refused. 
Thanks.

Comment: Hi Kathy, why don't you show us some code, to get an idea what you tried so far?

Comment: Do you mean the Nginx configuration?

Answer (score 1):

I figure out what was wrong. least_conn load balancing technique was not the right to choose since it dose not persist session. I changed it to 
hash $remote_addr or hash_ip and it is working.